# Use array annotation with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have currently trouble understanding the following scenario: 
I have a multidimensional array of Strings and I want to address it by using pointers only but I always get a Segmentation Fault when using the array annotation on the pointer. This is just an example code I want to use the 3D array in a pthread so I want to pass it in via a structure as a pointer but it just doesn't work and I would like to know why? I thought pointers and arrays are functionally equivalent? Here is the sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(unsigned char ***ptr);

int main() {
  // Image of dimension 10 times 10
  unsigned char image[10][10][3];
  unsigned char ***ptr = image;

  memcpy(image[0][0], "\120\200\12", 3);

  // This works as expected
  printf("Test: %s", image[0][0]);

  func(image);

  return 0;
}

void func(unsigned char ***ptr) {
  // But here I get a Segmentation Fault but why??
  printf("Ptr: %s", ptr[0][0]);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You can't initialize an array with a function call, only with a literal list of initializers.

Comment: Declaring an array allocates space for the array, there's no need to call `malloc()`.

Comment: I need because the 10x10 were just an example in the real application this is dynamic and depends on the image dimension... The char[3] represent the RPG value from 0...255 for each pixel in the image

Comment: C allows variable-length arrays, so you can write `char test[height][width][3];`

Comment: @Barmar That's true but it still doesn't solve the problem with the pointer as in the structure I cannot define a variable length array, can I?

Comment: Post code that looks more like what you're really trying to do, and show the code that's trying to access the array element.

Comment: An array is not a pointer. `char ***ptr = test;` is not correct, because `test[0]` is an array, but `ptr[0]` is expected to be a pointer.

Comment: @Barmar hmm ok I see and how do I write it correctly? :)

Comment: See the answer where he uses `malloc()` to allocate the main array and arrays for each row.

Comment: @Barmar But then I only have a pointer to one pixel... I need to have a pointer to the entire image so I can pass it into a thread as a pointer and modify it there

Comment: you have a pointer to the array of pionters. Do you need all the pixels to be in contiguous memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169281/discussion-between-tom1991te-and-barmar).

Comment: [My congratulations on advancing in rank. :P](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It is missing this statement: `#include <string.h>`  for the function: `memcpy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe `strdup` confuses the issue.  Pointers and arrays are *not* always equivalent.  Let me try to demonstrate.  I always avoid actual multi-dimension arrays, so I may make a mistake here, but:

```
int main()
{
  char d3Array[10][10][4]; //creates a 400-byte contiguous memory area 
  char ***d3Pointer; //a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a char.
  int i,j;
  d3Pointer = malloc(sizeof(char**) * 10);
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    d3Pointer[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10);
    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
      d3Pointer[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    }
  }
  //this
  d3Pointer[2][3][1] = 'a';
  //is equivalent to this
  char **d2Pointer = d3Pointer[2];
  char *d1Pointer = d2Pointer[3];
  d1Pointer[1] = 'a';


  d3Array[2][3][1] = 'a';
  //is equivalent to 
  ((char *)d3Array)[(2 * 10 * 4) + (3 * 4) + (1)] = 'a';
}
```

Generally, I use the layered approach.  If I want contiguous memory, I handle the math myself..like so:

```
  char *psuedo3dArray = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10 * 10 * 4);
  psuedo3dArray[(2 * 10 * 4) + (3 * 4) + (1)] = 'a';
```

Better yet, I use a collection library like `uthash`.

Note that properly encapsulating your data makes the actual code incredibly easy to read:

```
typedef unsigned char byte_t;
typedef struct
{
  byte_t r;
  byte_t g;
  byte_t b;
}pixel_t;

typedef struct
{
  int width;
  int height;
  pixel_t * pixelArray;
}screen_t;

pixel_t *getxyPixel(screen_t *pScreen, int x, int y)
{
  return pScreen->pixelArray + (y*pScreen->width) + x;
}

int main()
{
  screen_t myScreen;
  myScreen.width = 1024;
  myScreen.height = 768;
  myScreen.pixelArray = (pixel_t*)malloc(sizeof(pixel_t) * myScreen.height * myScreen.width);
  getxyPixel(&myScreen, 150, 120)->r = 255;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for :) I just thought too complicated but actually it is solvable with just a simple pointer :)

Comment: @tom1991te - You'll also save yourself a lot of headache with `struct pixel {byte r;byte g; byte b;}` or whatever C's garbage syntax for declaring structs is.  Now you have a 2-dimensional array...which is what it really is.  (Plus if the compiler can speed things up by 4/8-byte-aligning the structs, it will....)

Answer (score 1):

In C, you should allocate space for your 2D array one row at a time.  Your definition of test declares a 10 by 10 array of char pointers, so you don't need to call malloc for it.  But to store a string you need to allocate space for the string.  Your call to strcpy would crash.  Use strdup instead.  One way to write your code is as follows.

```
    char ***test = NULL;
    char *ptr = NULL;
    test = malloc(10 * sizeof(char **));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            test[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
    }
    test[0][0] = strdup("abc");
    ptr = test[0][0];

    printf("%s\n", ptr);

    test[4][5] = strdup("efg");
    ptr = test[4][5];

    printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your 10 by 10 definition, you could code it like this:

```
    char *test[10][10];
    char *ptr = NULL;

    test[0][0] = strdup("abc");
    ptr = test[0][0];

    printf("%s\n", ptr);

    test[4][5] = strdup("efg");
    ptr = test[4][5];

    printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

Comment: But it is actually a 3D array? I have a 2D array of arrays of chars of size 3... The array should represent an image and the chars should represent the RPG values from 0 to 255 for each pixel in the image

Comment: @tom1991te How about `char test[10][10][3];`?

Comment: if you know that each string only has 3 characters, then you could change the declaration to `chat test [10][10][4];` adding an extra char to hold the null terminator.  If you don't need the null terminator then use 3 and not 4.  If you don't have the null terminator, you can't use standard C library string functions like `strcpy` which will want to append the null byte at the end.

Comment: @bruceg yes I don't need the null terminator as these aren't really strings but just values for the pixels. But still why does `ptr[0][0]` not work? I need to pass in this array to a pthread as a structure argument and I cannot use the variable length array in a structure but have to use the `char ***ptr` :)

Comment: I think that you're crashing because ptr is holding the address of test. But, you won't be able to iterate through your 3D array with a ptr.  Not sure what you are planning to do with ptr.

Comment: @bruceg Yeah actually the goal is to iterate over the 3D array with a pointer

Comment: If you declare ptr like this: `unsigned char *ptr;` and assign it like this: `ptr = test[0][0];` Then you can iterate over the array like this: `  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          f(ptr);
          ptr++;
  }
` But, note that since you ptr doesn't know that it's pointing to a 3 character element.  All the data in test is laid out contiguously, so ptr at the beginning looks like a 300 character unterminated string.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that a `char[10][10][3]` is something **very different** from a `char***`: The first is an array of arrays of arrays, the later is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer. The confusions arises because both can be dereferenced with the same syntax. So, here is a bit of an explanation:

1. **The syntax `a[b]` is nothing but a shorthand for `*(a + b)`**: First you perform pointer arithmetic, then you dereference the resulting pointer.

   But, how come you can use `a[b]` when `a` is an array instead of a pointer? Well, because...
2. **Arrays decay into pointers to their first element**: If you have an array declared like `int array[10]`, saying `array + 3` results in `array` decaying to a pointer of type `int*`.

   But, how does that help to evaluate `a[b]`? Well, because...
3. **Pointer arithmetic takes the size of the target into account**: The expression `array + 3` triggers a calculation along the lines of `(size_t)array + 3*sizeof(*array)`. In our case, the pointer that results from the array-pointer-decay points to an `int`, which has a size, say 4 bytes. So, the pointer is incremented by `3*4` bytes. The result is a pointer that points to the fourths `int` in the array, the first three elements are skipped by the pointer arithmetic.

   Note, that this works for arrays of any element type. Arrays can contain bytes, or integers, or floats, or structs, or other arrays. The pointer arithmetic is the same.

   But, how does that help us with multidimensional arrays? Well, because...
4. **Multidimensional arrays are just 1D arrays that happen to contain arrays as elements**: When you declare an array with `char image[256][512];` you are declaring a 1D array of 256 elements. These 256 elements are all arrays of 512 characters, each. Since the `sizeof(char) == 1`, the size of an element of the outer array is `512*sizeof(char) = 512`, and, since we have `256` such arrays, the total size of `image` is `256*512`. Now, I can declare a 3D array with `char animation[24][256][512];`...

---

So, going back to your example that uses

```
char image[10][10][3]
```

what happens when you say `image[1][2][1]` is this: The expression is equivalent to this one:

```
*(*(*(image + 1) + 2) + 3)
```

1. `image` being of type `char[10][10][3]` decays into a pointer to its first element, which is of type `char(*)[10][3]` The size of that element is `10*3*1 = 30` bytes.
2. `image + 1`: Pointer arithmetic is performed to add `1` to the resulting pointer, which increments it by `30` bytes.
3. `*(image + 1)`: The pointer is dereferenced, we are now talking directly about the element, which is of type `char[10][3]`.
4. This array again decays into a pointer to its first element, which is of type `char(*)[3]`. The size of the element is `3*1 = 3`. **This pointer points at the same byte in memory as the pointer that resulted from step 2. The only difference is, that it has a different type!**
5. `*(image + 1) + 2`: Pointer arithmetic is performed to add `2` to the resulting pointer, which increments it by `2*3 = 6` bytes. Together with the increment in step 2, we now have an offset of `36` bytes, total.
6. `*(*(image + 1) + 2)`: The pointer is dereferenced, we are now talking directly about the element, which is of type `char[3]`.
7. This array again decays into a pointer to its first element, which is of type `char*`. The size of the element is now just a single byte. **Again, this pointer has the same value as the pointer resulting from step 5, but a different type.**
8. `*(*(image + 1) + 2) + 1`: Pointer arithmetic again, adding `1*1 = 1` bytes to the total offset, which increases to `37` bytes.
9. `*(*(*(image + 1) + 2) + 1)`: The pointer is dereferenced the last time, we are now talking about the `char` at an offset of `37` bytes into the `image`.

---

So, what's the difference to a `char***`? **When you dereference a `char***`, you do not get any array-pointer-decay**. When you try to evaluate the expression `pointers[1][2][1]` with a variable declared as

```
char*** pointers;
```

the expression is again equivalent to:

```
*(*(*(pointers + 1) + 2) + 3)
```

1. `pointers` is a pointer, so no decay happens. Its type is `char***`, and it points to a value of type `char**`, which likely has a size of `8` bytes (assuming a 64 bit system).
2. `pointers + 1`: Pointer arithmetic is performed to add `1` to the resulting pointer, which increments it by `1*8 = 8` bytes.
3. `*(pointers + 1)`: The pointer is dereferenced, we are now talking about the pointer value **that is found in memory at an offset of `8` bytes of where `pointers` points**.
4. Further steps depending on what actually happened to be stored at `pointers[1]`. These steps do not involve any array-pointer-decay, and thus load pointers from memory instead.

---

You see, the difference between a `char[10][10][3]` and a `char***` is profound. In the first case, the array-pointer-decay transforms the process into a pure offset computation into a multidimensional array. In the later case, we repeatedly load pointers from memory when accessing elements, all we ever have are 1D arrays of pointers. And it's all down to the types of pointers!