# C - create appending matrix

Tags: c, matrix, append

I don't exactly know if appending is the right term, but here's the problem explained:

I want to create an `M`, which is let's say a `5*5` matrix of strings starting with an element (let's say the character `5`). The first row of the matrix will look like this:

```
51 52 53 54 55
```

After that I'll take the content of `M[1][1]` and 'append' it to the respective columns, creating the second row:

```
 51  52  53  54  55
511 512 513 514 515
```

Then taking the content of `M[1][2]` to create the third row:

```
 51  52  53  54  55
511 512 513 514 515
521 522 523 524 525
```

At the end, `M` will look like this:

```
 51  52  53  54  55
511 512 513 514 515
521 522 523 524 525
531 532 533 534 535
541 542 543 544 545
```

If let's say the matrix is `7*7` then the 7th row will take the content of `M[2][1]` and 'append' it to the respective columns as below:

```
5111 5112 5113 5114 5115
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define RowMin 1
#define RowMax 7
#define ColMin 1
#define ColMax 7

/* here, I define a type called MATRIX, containing Mem (matrix of strings), 
   number of effective rows, and number of effective columns.
   My matrix will start from 1 and with 8 valid row and 8 valid column */
typedef struct { 
    char Mem[RowMax+1][ColMax+1];
    int NRowEff;
    int NColEff;
} MATRIX;

/* these are the selectors */
#define NRowEff(M) (M).NRowEff
#define NColEff(M) (M).NColEff
#define Elmt(M,i,j) (M).Mem[(i)][(j)]

void MakeMATRIX (int NR, int NC, MATRIX * M)
/* This is a procedure to create a matrix with predefined NR and NC */
{
    NRowEff(*M) = NR;
    NColEff(*M) = NC;
}

void CreateAppend (MATRIX *M, int NR, int NC, char elmt)
/* this is the procedure to create the matrix as defined in the problem */
{
    MakeMATRIX(NR,NC,M); /* first we make the matrix */
    /* these two are counters */
    int i = 1;
    int k = RowMin + 1; 

    /* to create the first row, I call this procedure */
    Append(M,i,&elmt);

    /* the next rows will be created with this loop */
    for (int i = RowMin; i <= NRowEff(*M); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = ColMin; j <= NColEff(*M); ++j)
        {
            /* first i take the element of the matrix that i want to append 
            */
            elmt = Elmt(*M,i,j);
            /* call the append procedure */
            Append(M,k,&elmt);
            /* add 1 to the counter */
            if (k <= NRowEff(*M))
                k++;
        }
    }
}

void WriteMATRIX (MATRIX M)
/* this is a procedure to write matrix to the screen */
/* e.g. writing 3 x 3 matrix will look like this
   1 2 3
   4 5 6
   8 9 10
*/
{
    for (int i = RowMin; i <= NRowEff(M); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = ColMin; j <= NColEff(M); ++j)
        {
            printf("%s", Elmt(M,i,j));
            if (j < NColEff(M))
                printf(" ");
        }
        if (i != NRowEff(M))
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void Append (MATRIX *M, int i, char * elmt)
/* this is the implementation of Append procedure that is called in 
   CreateAppend */
{
    char appendix[2];

    for (int j = ColMin; j <= NColEff(*M); ++j)
    {
        /* because I'm appending the respective column number to the elmt, I 
           will have to cast int to a const char* using sprintf */
        sprintf(appendix,"%d",j);
        /* then I append the elmt and the appendix using strcat */
        strcat(elmt, appendix);
        /* the new element of the matrix is elmt */
        Elmt(*M,i,j) = *elmt;
    }
}
```

In the main program, I write this:

```
int main(void)
{
    MATRIX MCPU;
    char elmt;

    elmt = '5';

    CreateAppend(&MCPU,5,5,elmt);
    WriteMATRIX(MCPU);
}
```

When I run this program in debug, I get a segmentation fault. I don't really know where do I mess up and if someone can point that out to me, it'll be helpful! Also I guess the loop isn't working right, but I fail to notice the mistake.

Comment: You should post this code here:  https://www.onlinegdb.com/  You will notice three typos that prevent it from compiling.  If you fix those, and then edit your answer with the correct code, you'll have better luck getting an answer.  You can also read the help on how to debug while you're there.

Comment: Also, I find this code incomprehensible, but `Mem` is not a matrix of strings, but a matrix of characters.  So that's a fundamental flaw right there.  You also should *really* not fight that C-arrays are 0-based.  It will cause you nothing but problems.

Comment: `char elmt ...  Append(M,i,&elmt);` is a call with a pointer of **1** `char`.    Yet `Append (MATRIX *M, indeks i, char * elmt) ... 
        strcat(elmt, appendix);` is looking for a place to store a _string_.  Not enough room.

Comment: Hi, @zzxyz . Thanks for pointing out! I notice the typos because previously the variable names were in my mother tongue and now I'm trying to translate the variable names to english.

Comment: @eniruure - I figured as much.  It's a pretty well-asked question, overall.

Comment: @chux - So the flaw is that I create a matrix of char to store strings. Correct me if I'm wrong. If so, I'll try to work it out some more and see if I can solve it.

Comment: @eniruure A `char` can only save a string of `""`.  Every other _string_ requires more than 1 `char`.  Good luck.

Comment: Check out my answer here to a very similar problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909386/use-array-annotation-with-pointers/49910273#49910273

Comment: @eniruure - Did you get this figured out?